# Display Salesforce static resource in javascript file

Tags: javascript, salesforce

In a javascript file, I want to display a PNG image stored as a static resource.

```
<img src="{!$Resource.myImage}">
```

I can see the `myImage` PNG in Eclipse so the PNG is available.
But the image is not displayed !

How can I display it ?

Comment: The Javascript file is a static resource as well?

Comment: Yes ! That's why I think writing that will be sufficient !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{!$Resource.<resourcename>}` will only work in Visualforce, not inside of static resources.

The best solution is to create a static resource zip file with the javascript and image files that will have this structure for example:

MyResources.zip:

```
.     <-- zip root
\js   <-- your js files
\img  <-- your images
```

And from your javascript file you can refer to the image using relative paths inside the zip file (your static resource):

```
  var imgsrc = '..\img\image.png';
```